# How to upgrade the angular compiler to process typescript 3+

Tags: angular, typescript

To fix a compiler probelem, I had to upgrade to typecript 3+, somehow I can't get the angular compiler to process it.

`ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.0 but 3.1.6
was found instead.`

I deleted `node_modules`, deleted `package-lock.json`, changed `package.json` and ran `npm install`. I took the version from a project I generated using `ng new`

As far as I read TS 3+ shold work with angular 7. So I tried it. Currently my package.json looks like this.

I could downgrade TS to fix this problem, but then I have the old issue, so this is NO option for me.

```
{
  "name": "workouttracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.9",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.14.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.3.2",
    "firebase": "^6.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-maps": "^3.3.0",
    "googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material": "^0.3.13",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.3",
    "ng2-img-max": "^2.1.18",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.49",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Installed Angular CLI

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.4
... common, compiler, core, forms, http, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/animations               7.2.15
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@angular/compiler-cli             6.1.10
@angular/fire                     5.2.1
@angular/language-service         6.1.10
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.16.4
```

I want to run ng build with no errors.

Comment: First try running `ng update` in order to update the compiler (and probably other angular modules) to update to _version 8_ which I think is the one requires version 3+ of TS. After that run `npm install`. The think is you have `"@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0"` which pins compiler to _version 7_ which seems to not accept version 3 of TS

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, but the same error

Comment: Ok, keep in mind sometimes it requires you to change the values manually in the package.json... if you want, you can take a look at this [`package.json`](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/client/package.json#L23) I have for an app running on Angular 8 with [TypeScript 3.4.2](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/client/package.json#L68)

Comment: Thanks, i found that my angular-cli was outdated, and my node.js too. So i tried upgrading, now i ran into this `npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@4.1.0: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`, any ideas?

Comment: If you upgraded your node.js installation maybe you will have to delete the `node_modules` folder an try again. If the error persists it might be due to the npm cache, but it's hard to tell to be honest. You could consider clearing the npm cache, but be sure you want to do that, most of the time I don't have any problem with that, but I've heard other devs around here on SO warning about it.

Comment: I think the problem is that the binaries you had are not compatible with the new node.js installation (or npm package manager)

Comment: After a lot of headach work i finally got it, i had to upgrade node.js, the easiest way, download the msi and install it. I took your `package.json` as an inpiration and did a lot of manual modifications to mine. and afeter all i got it working. thanks a lot

Comment: That's awesome! Well done :)

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:**

You are using:

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
```

And this is a 'slice' of the package json of @angular/compiler-cli version 6.x.x:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": ">=2.7.2 <2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "0.0.0-PLACEHOLDER"
  },
```

So yes, this version of compiler cli must use Typescript 2.7

**SOLUTION:**

You need to upgrade @angular/compiler-cli to a version **7.x.x**. And this makes totally sense in fact, since in order to use Angular 7, **all Angular packages must be at 7.x.x**.

This one: `"@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",` should have to be upgraded to 7.x.x too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: as I have to use typescript 3+ this isn't an option, read the question carefully

Comment: @ChristianBohli lol, I've read the question carefully, but you didn't on mine's answer. You have to upgrade @angular/compiler-cli to version ^7.0.0 like your other angular packages!! and the problem will go away... FYI I have edited my answer with the labels 'problem' and 'solution', hope now is more clearer...